# wine sources.list in focal has 3 entries for wine repository

Tags: wine, repository

Entries in focal sources.list:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main 
# disabled on upgrade to eoan disabled on upgrade to focal
deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main
deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main
```

I think I should comment out:

```
deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main
deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main
```

And just leave:
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main

I don't know why upgrading distro didn't do this?

Answer (score 1):

These two repositories are for wine source code, not for packages. Because they are source code you can either remove these two lines by preceding them with a `#` character to comment them out or just leave them in `/etc/apt/sources.list`; it doesn't matter which. That's my explanation about why upgrading the release to 20.04 didn't do this. Instead of commenting these two lines out you can also delete them.

```
deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main
deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main
```